как восстановить панель запуска vs code

Понял, что просто так тыкать кнопки не очень хорошая затея, но я не знаю как вернуть панель запуска файла (ее нет и при отрытом файл), это первое, также, до этого, тоже тыкал просто так, и куда то делась именно кнопка запуска файла, тип значок плеера, и пытался как раз вернуть ииии...
Дополнение: вот так при открытом файле: 
а также более подробное объяснение моей проблемы:


сложно понять, что вам необходимо. Объясните более подробно: какой файл запускается, есть ли расширения в vscode, где должна эта панель распологаться. Это необходимо поскольку vscode очень гибко кастомизируемая вещица, да к тому же для разных ЯП и разных окружений может настраиваться и вести себя по разному. Короче, больше деталей

Покажите как выглядит при открытом файле. Панель запуска находится в панели вкладок, возможно вы панель вкладок отключили.

@Dmitry - обновил вопрос

@insolor - обновил

Нажмите меню View -> Appearance -> Tab bar -> Multiple tabs

Хоть и выпендриваюсь в комментариях по этому поводу, но для начала, можете вернуть эту панельку

Насколько я вижу, у вас все равно не появится кнопка запуска, так что потом делайте то, что ниже.
Правой кнопкой мыши на трех точках в правом верхнем углу.
Выбрать Run Code

По следам комментария


См. второй скриншот, там вообще панели табов нет, и всего что в ней находится

@insolor может так и положена, у автора три точки просто чуть выше и выглядит как второй скрин

Да там просто панель вкладок нужно вернуть, раз он ее случайно скрыл, а не искать запуск кода под всякими точками

@insolor а как вам это понятно стало?) ну не первый же раз. Вопрос: верните кнопку "Run". Ответ: возвращаю. А додумывать не мое дело

Как это понятно стало - по отсутствию панели вкладок, это прямо очевидно, не нужно ничего додумывать и искать что-то под точками.

@insolor даже если он вернет эту панель, там же видно, что кнопку run ТС все рано не получит. Что вы так взведены, я полностью позитивен и на вашей стороне)

Как вам понятно стало, что он кнопку не получит?

@insolor симитировал на своем точно такой же интерфейс как и у ТС, и стало понятно

Я аналогично сымитировал точно такой же интерфейс, и кнопка после возвращения панели вкладок появилась. Я думаю тут стоит остановиться, и подождать комментов от ТС, не известно, что там на самом деле он нащелкал.

@insolor так я с самого начала за это) а мытут развели на пустом месте)
